# SysPrep Windows 10 Pro Error (0x0f0070 & 0x0f00d8)

Tags: sysprep, windows-10

So I seem to be experiencing an issue where Windows 10 and Windows Store apps (I am assuming) are interfering with Sysprep /oobe /generalize.

**When I attempt to run the above command, I receive the following error in the *setuperr.log***:

```
Error              SYSPRP Package Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.0_1.0.22929.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe was installed for a user, but not provisioned for all users. This package will not function properly in the sysprep image.
Error              SYSPRP Failed to remove apps for the current user: 0x80073cf2.
Error              SYSPRP Exit code of RemoveAllApps thread was 0x3cf2.
Error   [0x0f0082] SYSPRP ActionPlatform::LaunchModule: Failure occurred while executing 'SysprepGeneralizeValidate' from C:\Windows\System32\AppxSysprep.dll; dwRet = 0x3cf2
Error              SYSPRP SysprepSession::Validate: Error in validating actions from C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\ActionFiles\Generalize.xml; dwRet = 0x3cf2
Error              SYSPRP RunPlatformActions:Failed while validating SysprepSession actions; dwRet = 0x3cf2
Error   [0x0f0070] SYSPRP RunExternalDlls:An error occurred while running registry sysprep DLLs, halting sysprep execution. dwRet = 0x3cf2
Error   [0x0f00d8] SYSPRP WinMain:Hit failure while pre-validate sysprep generalize internal providers; hr = 0x80073cf2
Error              SYSPRP Package Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.0_1.0.22929.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe was installed for a user, but not provisioned for all users. This package will not function properly in the sysprep image.
Error              SYSPRP Failed to remove apps for the current user: 0x80073cf2.
Error              SYSPRP Exit code of RemoveAllApps thread was 0x3cf2.
Error   [0x0f0082] SYSPRP ActionPlatform::LaunchModule: Failure occurred while executing 'SysprepGeneralizeValidate' from C:\Windows\System32\AppxSysprep.dll; dwRet = 0x3cf2
Error              SYSPRP SysprepSession::Validate: Error in validating actions from C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\ActionFiles\Generalize.xml; dwRet = 0x3cf2
Error              SYSPRP RunPlatformActions:Failed while validating SysprepSession actions; dwRet = 0x3cf2
Error   [0x0f0070] SYSPRP RunExternalDlls:An error occurred while running registry sysprep DLLs, halting sysprep execution. dwRet = 0x3cf2
Error   [0x0f00d8] SYSPRP WinMain:Hit failure while pre-validate sysprep generalize internal providers; hr = 0x80073cf2
```

**I've had a look online at several articles only, namely**:

- [KB2769827](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2769827#)
- [TechNet Article "How to delete or remove "white" blank shortcut in shell:appsFolder"](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f4541494-8299-4809-b419-4ed5f063cac2/how-to-delete-or-remove-white-blank-shortcut-in-shellappsfolder?forum=win10itprogeneral)
- [Restore Microsoft Store application in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/949112/restore-microsoft-store-application-in-windows-10)

**The only things that I did when installing the system were these, in order**:

1. Installed Windows 10 Pro using "windows_multiple_editions" ISO from MSDN on an EFI VM;
2. Created a user "Admin" during the initial OOBE, logged in and ran **compmgmt.msc** and enabled built-in "Administrator";
3. Logged in as "Administrator", logged into a network share, ran installation scripts that install a bunch of programs;
4. Deleted "Admin" and did a VMware Snapshot before Sysprepping; and
5. Ran Sysprep.exe /oobe /generalize and received the above error doing so.

I took the initiative to try and fix this quickly by checking out Powershell's AppxPackage cmdlet but the below command returned no results:

```perl
Get-AppxPackage -AllUser | Where PublisherId -eq 8wekyb3d8bbwe | Format-List -Property PackageFullName,PackageUserInformation | Select-String "Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.0_1.0.22929.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe"
```

**I suppose my questions are**:

- Can this be fixed?
- What caused this, so that future troubled administrators will know how to avoid this?
- By deleting "Admin" have I somehow screwed something up (referring to the TechNet Article)?

I understand that there are answers for different Appx related issues, but I have not touched Windows Store/Metro Apps at all whilst sysprepping. The only notable thing I installed was .NET 3.5 (Related?)

To re-cap my VM setup is:

- Windows 10 Pro x64 (Build 10240);
- 2GB RAM, 60 GB HDD;
- EFI;
- Not domain joined. Currently on WORKGROUP; and
- Internet is NAT'd with VM host.

**Errors listed in the log file:**

- 0x0F0070
- 0x0F0082
- 0x0F00D8

I appreciate the feedback and answers. Hopefully someone will be able to outsmart this SysPrep error. Thanks for reading!

Comment: have you installed app updates? This broke sysprep in Win8.x.

Comment: magiandre1981: No. I only installed apps that were located on a network share offline. The only thing I "updated" was Adobe Reader XI to Adobe Reader DC via their installer. Aside from that, nothing else was updated. I can't run Windows Update because it re-installs ("upgrades") Windows 10 and sysprep cannot function on upgraded OS'.

Comment: Ever since Windows 8 with the introduction of the modern app stuff, sysprep has turned into a huge hassle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I managed to fix this by tinkering a bit with the Appx .NET package. I had a second user that was created during setup on VMware. "Admin" and "Administrator" were on the system. So I logged into "Admin" and ran:

```powershell
Remove-AppxPackage "Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.0_1.0.22929.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe"
```

I was then confronted with an error stating that "Microsoft.Skype" is using this .NET Runtime and removing the .NET package was not possible.

I had to quickly search for the correct package that this error was referring to by issuing the Powershell command:

```powershell
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Select-String "Microsoft.Skype"
```

It then showed a single Microsoft.Skype Appx Package!

I then removed the "Microsoft.Skype" Appx Package and proceeded to run the above command, it worked!

My next step was to do the same on "Administrator". So I did the above and ran Sysprep again, boom! It works. Hopefully this helps someone in the future. :)

**TL;DR:**

1. Attempt to remove Appx package on any other user except the built-in
   Administrator, this should throw an error/conflict with another App;
2. Search for the App using the above *Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers* command
3. Remove the conflicting application to the be able to remove the
   primary issue-raising application;
4. Do this for all users, including the built-in Administrator; and
5. Sysprep should work again.

Comment: For me this didnt seem to work. i also had to uninstall solidaire package and now im stuck. i can't uninstall microsfot.net.native.runtime it says package is not installed

Comment: Had to uninstall several other packages as well, but the general concept was the same.

Comment: @joelharkes - This could be because other users have the App installed on their profile. Have you followed the above and checked all users? This will also cause an issue if you delete a user as the SID is still registered as having it installed. Haven't figured that one out!

Comment: This fixed our issue thank you! For some reason solitaire was messing with my sysprep process, after running this command in a PowerShell window it fixed it right up. Remove-AppxPackage "Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection_3.9.5100.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe"